# Fabric build and run sign up error

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I've got this error:

```
Fabric: This app relies on Fabric. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install Fabric.app then ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.

If this machine is a build server please remove Fabric.app if present and use xcodebuild so that Portfolium.app.dSYM is uploaded.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

But I have logged in in fabric app and it works for me before.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed I delete app to trash. That's why it caused this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Again install fabric app in simulator.
please follow this

please find fabric in spotlight and and run again and try it.

also go check with this link
[How to integrate fabric with Xcode 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065965/how-to-integrate-fabric-with-xcode-6-2)

Comment: Your answer makes little sense.  "install fabric app in simulator"?  The app is a Mac app, not an iOS app.  The first link is broken.

Comment: how can we add mac app in simulator?