# How to integrate fabric with Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

i want to know how to implement the fabric with Xcode.am installed the fabric in mac,but unable the complete the process.it's still running with to continue build your project,i have built my project also.Any one help me

Comment: are you trying with simulator or device?I am also faced this issue when i selected "set  the device scheme" as iPhone device not worked.i changed into simulator then its worked

Comment: am trying in simulator

Comment: then try with quite the fabric and xcode then restart your work from begining.build your project again ..

Comment: Now it is in verifying installation stage.it showing your kit isn’t activating.if you are using the simulator,restart it and run your app again.i have closed the simulator and Xcode,reopen again,but still it is in same process

Comment: could you share screen shot where you sturggling?

Comment: can't you update to Xcode 6.3.2? I have installed Fabric two days ago and it works like charm

Comment: @karthikeyan- i have added the screen shot below.please check

Answer (score 21):

> Here is how I have implemented **Febric-SDK** into my app for **crash
> analytics**

Hope this will help someone out there.

1.After making signup —> go to

https://fabric.io/downloads

2.Download SDK for **Xcode**

[image]

3.Extract downloaded zip file and install Fabric.

now you can see Menu icon on top Status bar on your Mac.

Just **login** with register account on above screen.

[image]

and install Crashlytics by clicking **Install** button

[image]

4.Now it will guide you through step which help us to add script in Xcode

also ***it will give Script, Please copy and paste in text file on your mac, we need to use it later in Xcode settings***

here is the reference [link](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com/?utm_source=desktopapp&utm_medium=setup&utm_campaign=mac).

5.How to Add a Run Script Build Phase

let do it..

5.1. Go to Xcode project —> Build Phase —>

[image]

5.2. on left top corner click on “New Run Script Phase”

[image]

5.3. paste the script what you have copied earlier

[image]

Good we are almost done!!

5.4. Now in the Febric Menu go ahead you will guided for drag fabric kit icon to your Xcode project, which will actually add SDK to your project.

[image]

5.5. once you can see SDK frameworks (**Fabric.framework, Crashlytics.framework**) added to project, you need to configure AppDelegate file

5.5.1 add import statements

into AppDelegate.m file

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

5.5.2 now add “[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];” into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //todo here
    
    
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
        
    return YES;
}
```

6. Thats it!! you can goto Crashlytics Dashboard to see the report once you start debugging application

go to —>  https://www.fabric.io/settings  —> click on Dashboard button

[image]

Cheers!!

Comment: Good Explanation.

Comment: @RDC I am getting redirected to https://www.fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install when Im clicking on https://www.fabric.io/settings :(

Comment: is it paid service ?

Comment: @BKO is it paid service ?

Comment: fabric is awesome, and @NazmulHasan ```FREEEE``` (though some parts are paid) Beta/Crashlytics and Answers are two amazing tools that you should definitely tap in to. This was really hard to find however (the download links) so thanks BKO and swiftBoy

Comment: i have installed Fabric using cocoapods . so for that how to find Fabric api key and build secret ? do you know how ?

Answer (score 0):

Try quitting the helper and reopening it. I believe I had the same issue as you, it should pick up where it left off.

Comment: Try quitting the helper and reopening it,means.. sorry i didn't get u.please explain me

Comment: The little window from the menu bar that is showing, try quitting that and reopening it.

Comment: yes,i have tried that one,but it's not help me.could u please give any other suggestion.